# How to render a json object as a table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

First see the data I am receiving from the backend:

```
{
   "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0":{
      "clicks":{
         "total":144,
         "real":1
      },
      "conversions":{
         "total":4,
         "amount":229
      },
      "cost":{
         "cpc":0.1999999999999995,
         "ecpc":1145.0000000000027,
         "total":28.79999999999993
      },
      "revenue":{
         "total":4,
         "epc":0.027777777777777776
      },
      "net":{
         "roi":-1.1612903225806457,
         "total":4
      },
     "name":"Traffic Source #2",
   },       
   "55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4dbOTHER":{
      "clicks":{
         "total":144,
         "real":1
      },
      "conversions":{
         "total":4,
         "amount":229
      },
      "cost":{
         "cpc":0.1999999999999995,
         "ecpc":1145.0000000000027,
         "total":28.79999999999993
      },
      "revenue":{
         "total":4,
         "epc":0.027777777777777776
      },
      "net":{
         "roi":-1.1612903225806457,
         "total":4
      }
     "name":"Traffic Source #3"
   },

}
```

now the code, this html is exactly what I don't want:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>1 header</th>
            <th>2 header</th>
            <th>3 header</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="thing in things">
            <td>{{thing.asfs}}</td>
            <td>{{thing.asx}}</td>
            <td>{{person.dsf}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want something like this

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="head in heads">
        {{head}}
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="bar in bars">
        <td ng-repeat="foo in foos">{{foo[bar]}} //or whatever it is</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And also, sometimes that object will grow, could come up with some more keys like this one `55f6de98f0a50c25f7be4db0`

I did this fiddle with the exact same data I am receiving so maybe you can help me by playing in that Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kehaL8av/

This is the table that the designers gave to me to complete the task

[image]

where says Traffic Source, I need to render the key/value: `"name":"Traffic Source #3"` which comes in every object.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Do not close this one as I am going to be closing the last question I did because I edited many times, this is the question which is the one I need you to help me, the other is too verbose. Sorry.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am just asking for help as the data of this table is not coming up as I expect. So please, do not delete my question. If you don't want to help is OK.

Comment: You should convert to array, use `Array.map()` to create better formatted objects, then you can display your table better.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display an arbitrary set of columns in a specific order?

Comment: can you provide sample table that you expect for this data?

Comment: try to use [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kehaL8av/1/) as start

Answer (score -1):

Try using AngularJS - google AngularJS JSON tables